# jQuery mobile + ASP .NET MVC forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, forms-authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome on iOS shows weird url for jQuery Mobile page (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297287/chrome-on-ios-shows-weird-url-for-jquery-mobile-page-asp-net-mvc)

I have been using MVC for years, and just last night I started playing with jQuery mobile.  I developed a nice little mobile version of my application, and I can't figure out why this garbage is being prepended to my query string in all URLs beyond the logon page.

It looks like this:

```
http://hostname.com/application_name/(F(iPF1BcLSVortwvEsPbnDww4OLya-IL_-pZtm4zHaqOdzX8XJXVMs-PT_8oaW66SMq2NI2W9p7seVyD1xlYD-Bpj9sVUbFSmENn5vQz-kQagyIJyJCeaE5a3z_RXbtC4GPuntcFkK6ggf6MkzvTFVjb2isOc1))/area_name/controller_name/action_name/id
```

At the recommendation of someone on another post, I added this to my main mobile js library, but it didn't have any effect:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

It does NOT happen if I browse the site on a desktop browser, nor does it happen when I select "Request Desktop Site" on Chrome for iOS.

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: I guess may be the cookie got disabled in the device and hence the session id getting appended in the querystring

Comment: @Mark Good thought, to see if this was the case I printed HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID to the top of my main view, and I can confirm the garbage in the query string does NOT contain the SessionID